# Resize image in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, windows-10, python-imaging-library

So, I need to resize an image in tkinter. Before you do anything - this is not a duplicate. I have gone through every other question on this site and none have helped me. The thing with me is - I don't wan't to save the image. I need to load the image, resize it, then display it with PhotoImage in a label. I tried to use ImageTk, but for some reason it won't work.

Here's my code with ImageTk:

```
from tkinter import *
import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

left_nose_path_white = Image.open(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\Python stuff\Other apps\Veteris\Dog photos\Advanced\Sides\GIF\Nose\Nose (left) - White.gif')

def resize_image():
    global left_nose_path_white

    total_screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    total_screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

    frame_width, frame_height = left_nose_path_white.size

    dog_new_width = int(frame_width / 3)
    dog_new_height = int(frame_height / 3)

    left_nose_path_white = left_nose_path_white.resize((dog_new_width, dog_new_height), Image.LANCZOS)

resize_image()

left_nose_img_white = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = left_nose_path_white)
label = Label(image = left_nose_img_white)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This returns the error:

```
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 124, in __del__
    name = self.__photo.name
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'
```

My code should find the width and height of the original image, divide it by 3, and then show it. The reason I don't want to have to save the image is because the user will open the application several times.
I'm new to using PILL/Pillow, so the answer may be obvious.
I have Pillow installed using pip.
I only have one version of Python on my computer (Python 3.7)

Full Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Python stuff\Other apps\Veteris\Scripts\Veteris_program.py", line 230, in <module>
    left_nose_img_white = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = left_nose_path_white)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 95, in __init__
    image = _get_image_from_kw(kw)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 64, in _get_image_from_kw
    return Image.open(source)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2779, in open
    prefix = fp.read(16)
AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'read'
Exception ignored in: <function PhotoImage.__del__ at 0x000002B0A8A49950>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 124, in __del__
    name = self.__photo.name
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Replace `ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = left_nose_path_white)` with `ImageTk.PhotoImage(left_nose_path_white)`.

Comment: @Mike - SMT Oh wow! Thanks - I was losing my mind

Comment: Yep. Sometimes its the simple problems that take the longest to figure out :D. I have had that happen to me a few times.

Comment: Word of advice though. Don't go saying "This is not a duplicate". That will only serve to have people hunt down the duplicate and close your post. This is in fact a duplicate question that has been asked many times.

Comment: See similar question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71245789/how-to-define-an-image-object/71375732#71375732