# How to define an image object

Tags: python, image, tkinter

Here is a piece of code that picks up an image path from sqlite3, resize it to match a label/frame size and display it on a tkinter GUI. I don't know or don't remember how to define the variable "final_image," if the variable is only created *after* the GUI is started.

What I mean by this is that I have a list of records in a ttk.treeview. Each record has an image path inserted in the database. When I click on an item in the treeview, the selection is activating the function *preview_image()*, then resizes the image to fit an exact frame size on the GUI, and then display it.

The issue here is that until I click a record on the treevew, the variable "final_image" is null, so when I start the GUI, that variable is not defined, and the GUI fails.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import sqlite3


def preview_image():
    global img_link1, final_image

    Find path for selected record.
    conn = sqlite3.connect('Equipment.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    query = "SELECT c_ipath FROM items WHERE itemID LIKE '%" + record_value + "%'"
    c.execute(query)
    img_link = c.fetchone()


    c.close()
    conn.close()

    image = Image.open(img_link)
    img_link1 = image.copy()
    final_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)


def resize_image(event):
    new_width = event.width
    new_height = event.height
    img = img_link1.resize((new_width, new_height))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    img_label.config(image=photo)
    img_label.image = photo  # avoid garbage collection


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Title")
root.geometry('600x600')

# --------------------------------------- Tab 1 Image Preview -------------------------------
section3 = tk.Frame(root, background="black")
section3.place(x=10, y=10, height=460, width=500)

img_label = ttk.Label(section3, image=final_image)
img_label.bind('<Configure>', resize_image)
img_label.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES)

root.mainloop()
```

The solution might be very simple and obvious, but I can't see it.

Comment: What is the purpose of binding `<Configure>` on `img_label`? I don't see it is necessary.  Also you need to update `img_label` inside `preview_image()`.

Comment: @acw1668. It forces the image to resize automatically so that it fits the height of the frame (section3) of the GUI. Image sizes varies, so I am trying to have them fit in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of acw1668, I solved the issue with one function: I select a record from a treeview. This pulls the file path of the image from the database. Using the filepath, I resize the image on the fly and place it into a canvas. Every time I click a record on the treeview, it runs the preview_image(event) function and changes the image in the img_canvas with the resized image that fits the height of frame. This work for me, and it might help someone else.

The indicated corrections from acw1668 are in the comments below. Do not forget to make "final_img" global.

```
def preview_image(event):
    global final_img
    # Find path for selected record.
    conn = sqlite3.connect(conndb.data_source)
    c = conn.cursor()
    query = "SELECT c_ipath FROM items WHERE itemID LIKE '%" + record_value + "%'"
    c.execute(query)

    img_link = c.fetchone()

    c.close()
    conn.close()

    baseheight = 460
    img = Image.open(img_link[0])
    hpercent = (baseheight / float(img.size[1]))
    wsize = int((float(img.size[0]) * float(hpercent)))
    img_resized = img.resize((wsize, baseheight), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    
    final_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_resized)
    img_canvas.itemconfigure(image_item, image=final_img)


# --- GUI ----

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Title")
root.geometry('1120x980+500+20')

section3 = tk.Frame(root, background="black")
section3.place(x=10, y=510, height=460, width=1100)

img_canvas = tk.Canvas(section3, bg="black", highlightthickness=0)
img_canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES)
image_item = img_canvas.create_image(1100/2, 460/2, anchor=tk.CENTER)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: First you don't need to save the image to a file unless the image file will be used later in other situation.  Second you have created *new image item* and put at the same position in the canvas whenever the function is executed, better create a dummy image item (empty image) once and update its image inside the function.

Comment: acw1668@ Thank you. Can you show me how to create a dummy image item once and update its image inside the function?

Comment: Call `image_item = img_canvas.create_image(canvas_width/2, canvas_height/2)` once outside `preview_image()` and then use `img_canvas.itemconfigure(image_item, image=img)` inside the function.  Also why do you create a root window with size 600x600 but put a canvas of size 1100x460 at (10, 510)?

Comment: acw1668@ This works great. I corrected my code above with your instructions so that we have a final code that works.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this line

```
final_image = tk.PhotoImage()
```

after creating the root window.

---

OR

---

Simply remove the image attribute when you create the label

```
img_label = ttk.Label(section3)
```

Comment: Thank you. If I remove the image attribute when I create the label, I would then need to add the attribute back when running the function "preview_image()." Right?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. No matter what I do, one of the variables in the functions turns out to be undefined.