# Dynamic image resizing on Canvas-Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to upload an image to a drawing canvas in tkinter and it will be possible to resize the image dynamically as in word, powerpoint without resizing the screen itself but only the image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iby1Y.jpg)

Comment: You're going to have to write all the code to do that, there's nothing built-in to tkinter to support that.

Comment: See proposed solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71245789/how-to-define-an-image-object/71375732#71375732

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `tkinter` lacks the support for this particular task. It can resize the canvas dynamically, but not it's contents. You are going to need some other library like [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/), [NumPy](https://numpy.org/doc/)/SciPy, or `OpenCV`.

You can find more libraries by searching online or on [this](https://pythongeeks.org/image-processing-in-python/) website, which has a fairly nice tutorial regarding a the ones I mentioned as well as a few more.